# How to embed IPython kernel into PyQt4 program?

Tags: pyqt4, ipython

So according [to this PR on github](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/2724) the capability to embed a kernel into a PyQt4 program is now in the master.  Can anyone give an example of how to actually do it?  I can't find any documentation.  There was this previous attempt: [epatter's gist](https://gist.github.com/epatters/3659874) but the names of the modules must have changed because I can't even import.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code might help you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Set the QT API to PyQt4
import os
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt'
import sip
sip.setapi("QString", 2)
sip.setapi("QVariant", 2)
from PyQt4.QtGui  import *
# Import the console machinery from ipython
from IPython.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget import RichIPythonWidget
from IPython.qt.inprocess import QtInProcessKernelManager
from IPython.lib import guisupport

class QIPythonWidget(RichIPythonWidget):
    """ Convenience class for a live IPython console widget. We can replace the standard banner using the customBanner argument"""
    def __init__(self,customBanner=None,*args,**kwargs):
        if customBanner!=None: self.banner=customBanner
        super(QIPythonWidget, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.kernel_manager = kernel_manager = QtInProcessKernelManager()
        kernel_manager.start_kernel()
        kernel_manager.kernel.gui = 'qt4'
        self.kernel_client = kernel_client = self._kernel_manager.client()
        kernel_client.start_channels()

        def stop():
            kernel_client.stop_channels()
            kernel_manager.shutdown_kernel()
            guisupport.get_app_qt4().exit()            
        self.exit_requested.connect(stop)

    def pushVariables(self,variableDict):
        """ Given a dictionary containing name / value pairs, push those variables to the IPython console widget """
        self.kernel_manager.kernel.shell.push(variableDict)
    def clearTerminal(self):
        """ Clears the terminal """
        self._control.clear()    
    def printText(self,text):
        """ Prints some plain text to the console """
        self._append_plain_text(text)        
    def executeCommand(self,command):
        """ Execute a command in the frame of the console widget """
        self._execute(command,False)


class ExampleWidget(QWidget):
    """ Main GUI Widget including a button and IPython Console widget inside vertical layout """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExampleWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QPushButton('Another widget')
        ipyConsole = QIPythonWidget(customBanner="Welcome to the embedded ipython console\n")
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(ipyConsole)        
        # This allows the variable foo and method print_process_id to be accessed from the ipython console
        ipyConsole.pushVariables({"foo":43,"print_process_id":print_process_id})
        ipyConsole.printText("The variable 'foo' and the method 'print_process_id()' are available. Use the 'whos' command for information.")                           

def print_process_id():
    print 'Process ID is:', os.getpid()        

def main():
    app  = QApplication([])
    widget = ExampleWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```